# Uploading data and information(name,title) using asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

```
$('.submit').click(function () {
    var myData = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        resources: $('#resources').val(),
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/Action',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(this) + myData,
        processData: false  
    }).done(function () {

    }).fail(function () {

    });
});
```

This is my cs code

[HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult View(HttpPostedFileBase file,Info myinformation)
{
    //my problem is , debuggers gets hit in this controller but file and myinformation data are null . 
    return View("index");
}
```

There is no problem if i send myData in data . I'm doing it any wrong? or is there any other way so that i can upload my file and get additional data so that i can store in sql server .

So i would not like to use any jQuery plugins . :)

Thanks,

Comment: Is `#name` and `#resources` in the form with the file input?

Comment: @Musa yes they are . They can be anything from user ends.

Answer (score 0):

The Ideal solution would be to use a view model.

```
public class Create
{
public HttpPostedFileBase File {set;get;}
public Info MyInformation {set;get;} 
}
```

And your HttpPost action would be accepting an object of this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult View(Create model)
{
  // do something and return something
}
```

and ajax will be

```
$('.submit').click(function () {
var myData = {
    MyInformation: $('#name').val(),
    File: $('#resources').val(),
}
$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/Action',
    type: 'POST',
    data: myData,
    processData: false  
}).done(function () {

}).fail(function () {

});
});
```

Comment: Hmm value of file is null in the post back .

Comment: where do you pass value of file ?

Comment: I guess this $('#resources').val() is gives filename , doesnt pass whole file as i want :)

Comment: So what gives you whole file insert that. I can give you way , but you have to solve your own issue.

Comment: Eventually i separately did that. I made different actionresult for both of them . Not the best way but had no choice , had limited time . Thanks :)

Comment: http://rachelappel.com/upload-and-download-files-using-asp.net-mvc

This was helpfull